# How to parse a JSON without key in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, arraylist

Hi i am having a simple type of json response ,I have worked on JSON with keys but in this response i only have the values,Please see the response as below

**json**

```
{
status: "success",
country: [
{
1: "Afghanistan"
},
{
2: "Albania"
},
{
3: "Algeria"
},
{
4: "American Samoa"
},
{
5: "Andorra"
},
{
6: "Angola"
},
{
7: "Anguilla"
},
{
8: "Antarctica"
},
{
9: "Antigua and Barbuda"
},
{
10: "Argentina"
},
{.....
.
.
.
.
.so on..
```

So i want to parse this JSON and want to put both the values in an ArrayList of Hashmap,I have worked as below,But find no path to proceed,Hope some buddy will help me.

**code**

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                if (jsonObj.has("country")) {

                    CountryArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("country");
                    if (CountryArray != null && CountryArray.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts
                        System.out
                                .println("::::::::::::::::my talent  size:::::::::::"
                                        + CountryArray.length());
```

Comment: could you post your CountryArray please?

Answer (score 0):

The "status","country" and all the "1","2", etc in the json array "country" are all keys and hence, must be in double quotes. In short, your JSON is invalid.
Example:

```
{
"status": "success",
"country": [
{
"1": "Afghanistan"
}
]}
```

Comment: the numbers are not keys..Please read the quations carefully,I need the "both" number and country values .None of this is a key.

Comment: @Jims Then it is not JSON :D

Comment: numbers are integer .you getting me?

Comment: JSON Values
JSON values can be:

A number (integer or floating point)
A string (in double quotes)
A Boolean (true or false)
An array (in square brackets)
An object (in curly braces)
null

Answer (score 0):

**Your Json is not correct please check below format for your requirement.**

```
{
  status: "success",
  country: [
    {
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Albania",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Algeria",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "American Samoa",
      "value": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Andorra",
      "value": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Angola",
      "value": "6"
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: means i must have to change my json? its not possible to parse it that is your mean?

Comment: @Jims,I have just given right format for your json it all depend on you.

Comment: My question was how to parse this json..not change the format of json

Comment: @Jims,Yes i understood but json is parsed successfully when it is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it my way and wasted time in changing JSON syntax as answers suggested,my code is as below.

**code**

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(allContriesURL,
                    BackendAPIService.GET);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    if (jsonObj.has("country")) {
                        CountryArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("country");
                        if (CountryArray != null && CountryArray.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts
                            System.out
                                    .println("::::::::::::::::my talent  size:::::::::::"
                                            + CountryArray.length());
                            for (int i = 0; i < CountryArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = CountryArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                country_name = c.getString((i + 1) + "");
                                System.out
                                        .println(":::::::::::::::::::COUNTRY NAME:::::::::::::::::::::"
                                                + country_name);
                                HashMap<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                countryMap.put("country_id", i + 1 + "");
                                countryMap.put("name", country_name);
                                countryList.add(countryMap);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out
                        .println("::::::::::::::::::::::;;EXCEPTION::::::::::::::::"
                                + e);
            }
```