# Parsing JSONObject having dynamic key

Tags: android, json

I have following JSON as response from my server. At first, I thought, it was invalid JSON but after validating it, it seems to be correct:

```
JOSN: {
    "category": {
        "1": "World",
        "2": "Politics",
        "3": "Economy",
        "4": "Sports",
        "5": "Cricket",
        "6": "General",
        "7": "Business",
        "8": "Services",
        "9": "Law & Order",
        "10": "Entertainment"
    }
}
```

Validation: [image: JSON Validatiion]

If it would have been JSONArray, I would have parsed it with this solution from SO: [How to parse a JSON without key in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314145/how-to-parse-a-json-without-key-in-android)

But how do I parse the JSON I have here?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to get all the keys in JSONObject?

Comment: Yes, all the keys with their respective values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But how do I parse the JSON I have here?

if keys inside `category` JSONObject is dynamic then use `JSONObject.keys()` to get `Iterator` for getting values as:

```
JSONObject mainJSONObj=new JSONObject(<json_string>);
// get category JSONObject from mainJSONObj
JSONObject categoryJSONObj=mainJSONObj.getJSONObject("category");

// get all keys from categoryJSONObj

Iterator<String> iterator = categoryJSONObj.keys();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    Log.i("TAG","key:"+key +"--Value::"+categoryJSONObj.optString(key);
  }
```

Comment: +1 for letting me know about the `keys` idea. I have edited my answer and considered the `iterator` solution to the `Hashtable`

Comment: Hi this is working fine for 5+ versions. On kitkat 4.4 it give wrong sequence.What should I do?

Comment: @SAndroidD: As you know JSONObject is `unordered collection`. let me know which issue you are getting currently

Comment: actually My JSONObject collection in proper format. But when I get keys in Iterator these are not in sequence. For android version 5+ working perfect

Comment: @SAndroidD: Ok Why order is important? please share link if you posted any question

Comment: I requires it in order :)

Answer (score 12):

Try using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) deserialization with an object of such class as a serialization output class:

```
class MyClass {
    @SerializedName("category")
    private Map<String, String> categories;

    public Map<String, String> getCategories() {
       return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Map<String, String> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you and I'm sure that **the keys are a sequence of numbers starting with 1**, I would do the following:

```
Map<Integer, String> results = new Hashtable<>();

    try {
        //The response is your JSON as a string
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject categories = obj.getJSONObject("categories");

        int counter = 1;
        //Breakable infinite loop, will be broken when you try to get non existing item
        while(true){
            results.put(counter, categories.getString(counter+""));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//Return the map that contain the results
 return results;
```

Or using `Iterator` as the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573965/1364896) :

```
Map<Integer, String> results = new Hashtable<>();

    try {
        //The response is your JSON as a string
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject categories = obj.getJSONObject("categories");

        Iterator<String> iter = categories.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            results.put(key, categories.getString(key+""));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return the map that contain the results
    return results;
```

You can also create an `ArrayList<String>` and add the values to it instead of adding them to a `HashTable`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using custom class(bean) for storing list of categories instead of HashMap

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```
JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject("category");
    Iterator keys = obj.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        // loop to get the dynamic key
        String dynamicKey = (String) keys.next();

        String value= obj.getString(dynamicKey);
    }
```

For more information checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result). May be this will help you more.